# How to add classes to Symfony 4 “SubmitType” item labels?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

I added input[type=submit] with label, but i dont know how add custom class to label?
help me...

```
->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
         'label' => 'click me',
         'attr' => ['class' => 'c-form-input__input']
    ])
```

Comment: if you have the attr class defined in your view it will override whatever you define in the formType

Comment: @HerrNentu' the attr class added to input <input type="submit" id="form_symfony_save" name="form_symfony[save]" class="c-form-input__input">, but i want add class to label  <label for="form_symfony_save">click me</label>

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing your code with css in the first place. You should style your form theme instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your view:

```
{{ form_label(form.name, 'Your name', {
    'label_attr': {'class': 'CUSTOM_LABEL_CLASS'}
}) }}
```

Comment: no worries. just check the documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#label-attr